# How to read service parameters in DI container with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: dependency-injection, reflection, asp.net-core-6.0

For example I have configured a service

```
Builder.Services.AddRazorPages(Sub(options As RazorPagesOptions)
                 options.RootDirectory = "/"
                 options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/User")
           End Sub)
```

Than I want to read these options `RootDirectory` and `Conventions`.

I try to read, but failed. I can receive only list of parameters, for example

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions
0. ViewLocationExpanders : Of IList`1
1. ViewLocationFormats : Of IList`1
2. AreaViewLocationFormats : Of IList`1
3. PageViewLocationFormats : Of IList`1
4. AreaPageViewLocationFormats : Of IList`1

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions
0. Conventions : Of PageConventionCollection
1. RootDirectory : Of String
```

But for reading value by reflection (GetValue) I need instance of parameters, I don't understand how receive instance of service parameters.

Reading parameters list is simple, for example

```
Dim OptionTypeList = Builder.Services.Where(Function(X) X.ServiceType.IsGenericType).Select(Function(X) X.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()(0)).Distinct.ToList
OptionTypeList.ToList.ForEach(Sub(OneOptionType)
     Debug.Print($"{OneOptionType.FullName}")

     For J As Integer = 0 To OneOptionType.GetProperties.Count - 1
         Dim Prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo = DirectCast(OneOptionType, System.Reflection.TypeInfo).DeclaredProperties(J)

         If Prop IsNot Nothing Then
             Debug.Print($"{J}. {Prop.Name} : Of {Prop.PropertyType.Name}")
                                   '(0): {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.PageConventionCollection Conventions}
                                   '(1): {System.String RootDirectory}
```

But how to receive value of parameters? For example value of `Conventions` - where is the instance? Or reading parameters are possible without reflection `GetValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to read these options RootDirectory and Conventions.

In .net6, you can try to register the service in Program.cs like below:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Features");
```

Then in class,  you can read.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
       
        private readonly IOptions<RazorPagesOptions> _Options;
        public IndexModel( IOptions<RazorPagesOptions> Options)
        {         
            _Options=Options;   
        }
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: You can see how I transform your idea from my previous question about options (.IsGenericType and .GetGenericArguments()(0)) to useful code what print all options. I will try to inject all services and will create page with visualization all options of all services - this is my final goal for comparing all options of two projects. Because something my changing of working projects full destroy workable project (even including absolutely unrelated part routing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73226496/how-to-detect-reason-of-wrong-routing-in-asp-net-core-6 ) and I still can not find issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0), hope it will help.

Comment: this article dreaming me, but this article has no answer to main questions - how to create full list of endpoint. As you can see in my question - result of routing define as result of combine 13 or 7 attributes. Why and which case project has 13 routing attribute, why and each case 7. How to see value of routing attribute? What priority of attribute? This article is simple trash for students or newbie, this is not real useful articles for programmer, it not contains any sensitive information about inject routing attributes, reason to inject, value of routing attributes, priority and so on.